# Writing PhD thesis by copying and pasting paragraphs from publications I authored or co-authored: is this plagiarism?

Tags: publications, thesis, self-plagiarism

I'm planning to write my PhD thesis about the work I authored or co-authored in published journal. In this case, is it okay to simply copy and paste the paragraph from the paper to my thesis? Is this considered plagiarism if I am the author or co-author of the paper? I'm particular concerned for those papers that I'm not the first author.

Comment: What did your advisor say when you asked him/her this question?

Comment: Related: [How much overlap is permitted between a submitted journal article and a thesis?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2281/how-much-overlap-is-permitted-between-a-submitted-journal-article-and-a-thesis), [Can I reuse part of a paper for my thesis?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1897/can-i-reuse-part-of-a-paper-for-my-thesis), [Self-Plagiarism in PhD thesis](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12342/self-plagiarism-in-phd-thesis)

Comment: Also see [What is a “Sandwich thesis”?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/149/what-is-a-sandwich-thesis)

Comment: He said I can write whatever I want but I'm worry about my committees..

Comment: I marked as a duplicate the [question about third-authored paper](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41767/how-to-integrate-a-paper-where-i-am-third-author-but-did-a-lot-of-work-into-my) because you said you were especially concerned about the papers where you're not the first author. but note that there are also highly relevant answers on the other questions I linked to in my comment above.

Comment: okay, thanks. I'm very happy I found my answer-I can staple all my publications and sent them to my advisor..

Comment: Uh, that's not the answer... [this is the answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/58788/11365). You should really read *all* the answers to *all* the posts I linked.